# Search a string for any occurence of a word in a list of strings and higlight matched word if first character of word matches.Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/54o1hmz2/1/)
This works with [substring of word ][matches]. ideally which not match on substring.

if searched word **first character** matches with **first character of any words** in list of string to be searched. **matched characters** should be **highlighted**

```js
// Core function
function buildRegexFor(find) {
    return '(' + find + ')';
}

// Handle button click event 
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    // (1) read input
    var find = document.querySelector('input').value;
    var str = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

    // (2) build regular expression using above function
    var regexStr = buildRegexFor(find);

    // (3) apply regular expression to text and highlight all found instances   
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(regexStr, 'g'), "<strong class='boldtxt'>$1</strong>");

    // (4) output
    document.querySelector('span').textContent = regexStr;
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```css
.boldtxt {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Value to find:
<br>
<input value="eter">
<br>
<button>find</button>
<br> Text to find in:
<br>
<textarea cols=40>meter parameter eter water twitter eternal</textarea>
<br> Regex: <span></span>
<br>
<div></div>
```

.

words can have **special characters** as well which has to be highlighted if it matches.
Below is piece of code which i have tried to achieve. **eter**nal is only word in which **eter** should be highlighted, where as **eter** in Meter and Parameter should not be highlighted.

Comment: If we provide "eter % and @" as input  value to find. If we have "meter parameter @ eter water and twitter eternal %"  content in text area.In result "only eter % and @" content should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function that creates the regex to the following

```
function buildRegexFor(find) {
    return '(\\b' + find +')';
}
```

that will highlight only the occurrences of the string if they are at the beginning of the word or the word themselves. If I understood your question correctly, that is what you need.

Thanks

Paras